# Unable to connect to access database using PHP invalid file name

Tags: php, odbc

I am trying to connect with access database using *php*,

googled too much but still stuck with this:

```
<?php
    $dbName = "C:\Users\Parth\Documents\eTimeTrackLite1.mdb";
    $connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName");
```

Almost  both option show the same error:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name., SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\deconnect\dconnect.php on line 3

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `\e` is a special [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for a non-alphnumeric character (i.e., hex symbol):

> \e
>       escape (hex 1B)

Hence, the file path (which contains `\e` between folder and file name) you are passing into connection string fails to be a legitimate Windows path which can be seen with below example:

```
<?php

echo "C:\Users\Parth\Documents\eTimeTrackLite1.mdb";
echo "\n";
echo "C:\Path\To\Database\File.mdb";
echo "\n";

?>
```

Output

[image: Command Line Output Original]

To fix, simply double the backslash near `e` to escape this symbol:

```
echo "C:\Users\Parth\Documents\\eTimeTrackLite1.mdb";
```

Or better yet, double up all backslashes:

```
echo "C:\\Users\\Parth\\Documents\\eTimeTrackLite1.mdb";
```

[image: Command Line Output Fix]